# Запустить PHP скрипт отдельным потоком с массив данными

Tags: php, bash

Задача состоит в том, что б при запуске определенной команды, данные массива со скрипта A поступали на скрипт B. И этот скрипт принял эти данные и был запущен отдельным потоком, в не зависимости от скрипта A. Как это сделать и принять массив на том конце.
Был найдет вот такой код

```
exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid php send.php ' . escapeshellarg($data) . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');
```

где `$data` это просто некое значение, пока не массив. Но на том конце я не могу принять данные и не понятно работает ли оно. Как правильно построить код и передать/принять массив данные?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Все работает. Нужно лишь принимать данные через `$_SERVER['argv']`